# Разное поведение хуков жизненного цикла в vue/nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет, у меня есть две страницы foo и bar, я вывожу в консоль сообщение, когда каждый из хуков сработает. Во vue это один порядок, в nuxt — другой

**Vue:**

enter /foo

beforeCreate 
created 
beforeMount 
mounted

switch /foo to /bar

beforeCreate 
created 
beforeMount 
beforeDestroy 
destroyed 
mounted

**Nuxt:**

enter /foo

beforeCreate 
created 
beforeMount 
mounted

switch /foo to /bar

beforeDestroy 
destroyed 
beforeCreate 
created 
beforeMount 
mounted

Когда идет переход на /foo, то в vue/nuxt хуки срабатывают в одинаковом порядке, но если перейти с роута на роут, тогда порядок поменяется. Почему такое происходит? Может быть я делаю что-то не так?

[Песочница Vue](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-khorana-zbddxb?file=/src/views/bar.vue) 
[Пeсочница Nuxt](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-mountain-u1q5p6?file=/pages/foo.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказали на зарубежном stackoverflow, проблема была в том, что стандартно в **Nuxt** переход между страницами установлен в режим out-in, это можно поменять в nuxt.config.js в transition.mode:

```js
{
  transition: { 
    mode: 'in-out' 
  }
}
```